# iphone adding cells ontop of table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How do you add cells onto the top of the table, like when you pull down to get the latest tweets on the Twitter iPhone app...I'm not talking about the pull down method, more the adding the cells upwards rather than downwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really have anything to do with your table. It has to do with how your datasource is ordered.

In the:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)
```

you're responsible for setting up the cell for that index. A simple example:

```
//tweetsArray is an array that stores all our tweet model objects (Tweet class)

//Got a new tweet!
Tweet *newTweet = [self getNewTweet];
[tweetsArray insertObject:newTweet atIndex:0];
[myTableView reloadData];
```

The new tweet is now the first element in the array and should be the first element in your tableview if your logic is correct.

EDIT: So you want the new cells to be added to the top in the sense that if the user if scrolled all the way to the top and a new cell is added, it will be off-screen and he will have to scroll up to see it (sorry, I haven't used the Twitter app)?

In such a case, you can use [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, yPos)];

It could be a bit fiddly but the basic idea is to calculate the height of the new cells and add it to the current offset. i.e., if each cell is 40 points high:

```
offsetDisplacement = numNewCells * 40;
    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, tableView.contentOffset.y + offsetDisplacement)];
```

Try something like that.

Comment: So youre saying add cells with index -1, -2, -3, etc...?

Comment: No, the index should be 0. The other objects should automatically be repositioned.

Comment: but, like the twitter app, i want them to be added to the top but the current table position stay static.